# Not compiling printf in haskell

Tags: haskell

guys please tell me why this is not compiling

```
putStrLn("The average number of fans for the films of " ++ actor ++ " is : " ++ printf "%.2f\n" (show(countAveFans actor testDatabase))
```

Its to simple but i cant think why it doesnt work.I try to convert the whole thing to string and take the 2 decimal point print out.Thanks

Comment: You might want to avoid `printf`. It's pretty weird.

Comment: But if you want to use it, you should probably use it for the whole string: `putStrLn $ printf "The average ... films of %s is: %.2f" actor (countAveFans actor testDatabase)`

Comment: @dfeuer If you're using it for the whole string, note that `printf ...` can also be used as an `IO` action, so you don't need the `putStrLn`. (Although you then need an extra `\n`.) However, I suspect using it on the whole string is actually less efficient, because it then needs to parse at runtime the parts of the string that don't contain `%`s...

Comment: Also, if you *do* try to avoid `printf` here, the function you want to use instead is probably `showFFloat` from the `Numeric` module. Note that it's a `ShowS` function so it has a last argument that is a string to prepend to.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen, `printf` is more a type system magic trick than a practical function, as far as I can tell. If you're going to do silly tricks, you might as well go all the way, right? I didn't realize it could also be `IO()`; that's pretty funny.

Comment: I'm not sure what's so weird about `printf`, I use it all the time.

Answer (score 7):

You need to supply a `RealFloat` instead of a `String` to `printf` so remove the call to `show`:

```
putStrLn $ "The average number of fans for the films of " ++ actor ++ " is : " ++ (printf "%.2f\n" $ countAveFans actor testDatabase)
```